# Why was Adobe Reader in Chrome disabled by browser?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, adobe-reader

Adobe Reader in Chrome is disabled by the browser. Does anyone have any ideas as to why?

All users are up to date on both Chrome and Adobe Reader versions.

Comment: Have you tried to enable it?  This on a personal or company computer?

Comment: Chrome has a built-in PDF viewer so Adobe Reader is generally useless unless you are experiencing some edge-case scenario where Chrome's PDF viewer is rendering the PDF incorrectly

Answer (score 2):

Google says:

> By default, Chrome uses a built-in PDF viewer to open PDFs. If you've disabled the built-in PDF viewer, Chrome will use Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader to display PDFs. Follow the suggestions below if you're having trouble viewing PDFs within Chrome, using Adobe Acrobat or Adobe Reader.

To disable the built-in viewer, enter chrome:plugins in the address bar and click Disable underneath the entry for “Chrome PDF Viewer.” The Adobe Reader plug-in will automatically be enabled, if you have it installed.